# Change nickname of attention seekers in discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a command in discord.js bot by which when used **d!noattention member** it gets all the users in the server who have special characters at the starting of their username or nickname and changes their nickname to **member**
My code is :

```
const options = [
           "!",
           "?",
           '/',
           '\'',
           '~',
           '#',
           '@',
           '+',
           '=',
           '(',
           '*',
           '&',
           '^',
           '%',
           '$',
           '[',
           '`',
           '1',
           '2',
           '3',
           '4',
           '5',
           '6',
           '7',
           '8',
           '9',
           '_',
           '-',
           '.',
           '¿'
];

module.exports = {
  name: "noattention",
  aliases: ["attentionnick", "anick"],
  description: "Change nickname of all the attentions seekers to something you want.",
  category: "moderation",
  usage: "<new nickname>",
  run: async(client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_NICKNAMES"])) return message.reply("You do not have permission to use this command.").then(m => m.delete(15000));
    const name = args.join(" ");
    if(!name) return message.reply("Also provide the new nickname you want for attention seekers.").then(m => m.delete(15000));
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const user = message.guild.members.filter(m => m.displayName.startsWith(options[i]));
    user.forEach(u => u.setNickname(name));
    }
    message.channel.send(`Successfully changed nicknames of all attention seeking members`);
  }
}
```

It is working well but i also want it to send me and tell how many user's nickname has been changed. When i try to put the `message.channel.send` code under `for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++)` so that it can get the value of `user` the bot starts spamming the message and doesn't say the number of users.
`user.length` is not working here.

Comment: Welcome @Ronak. Try and make sure your code is easy to read and only includes the parts relevant to the question. You're more likely to get good answers that way. When I open this question, the options array takes up most of it. It doesn't even seem relevant to the question. Several lines of your run function require horizontal scrolling to read. You're more likely to get good answers if you make answering easy.

Answer (score 1):

You must put some var outside the for loop and add `user.length` to it from the for loop. Then the var will have the final number. When you will send messages directly from the loop, it will spam because there is no sum operation, so it will log every value from the loop to the channel. When you will put the line outside the loop, the user variable will be undefined, because you define user inside the loop.

Comment: Can you tell me the code about what you are saying? I didn't understand what u meant. If i will put the **const user** code outside of thr loop code, it will not be able to get the value of **i** in **options[i]**

Comment: @Ronak, put there something as this before the loop `var userCount = 0;` and inside the loop do `userCount = userCount + user.length`, then after the loop, the userCount var will have the result you need. (sry for bugs, I am on mobile)

Comment: I tried it and it is not working. bot sends the message and the place where there should be user count, there is **NaN** :/ @doc. Chocholoušek

Comment: `var usercount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const user = message.guild.members.filter(m => m.displayName.startsWith(options[i])); usercount = usercount + user.length;
    user.forEach(u => u.setNickname(name));
    }
    message.channel.send(\`Successfully changed nicknames of ${usercount} attention seeking members\`);
 ` _(the usercount code inside the loop code is in new line.. i am on phone so it is not letting me make it on new line)_

Comment: Wait, what version of discord.js are you using? Because in new versions, there is guild member manager, so for getting collection, you need to use `guild.members.cache`.

Comment: i am using v11.5.1

Comment: And what is the output, when you try to console.log length of the collection?

Comment: it is NaN when I do as what u said and it is undefined when I put user.length in the loop code.

Comment: Ok, this isn't best way how to do it, but you can do collection#array().length.

Comment: ok, thanks. It worked.
I created **usercount** as an array and in the code **user.forEach()** I pushed the value and array.length() worked!